# C++ Error 'nullptr was not declared in this scope' in Eclipse IDE

Tags: c++, g++, eclipse-cdt

I am running Eclipse Helios and I have g++-4.6 installed. Hope I am not wrong that g++4.6 implements C++ 11 features. I have created a C++ project which uses the nullptr and auto keywords. The build gives the following errors:-

```
../{filename}.cpp:13:13: error: ‘nullptr’ was not declared in this scope

../{filename}.cpp:14:2: warning: ‘auto’ will change meaning in C++0x; please remove it [-Wc++0x-compat]
```

Actually it was building fine until yesterday. I am getting these from nowhere today. Please help me solve this problem.

Comment: What is the exact version of g++ and what compile options are you using?

Comment: Please post a code sample that exhibits this behaviour, without that we're trying to read tea leaves here.

Comment: I am using g++ 4.6, and imagine lines of code like this:-
int* ptr = nullptr;
auto x = 123;

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Finally found out what to do. Added the -std=c++0x compiler argument under Project Properties -> C/C++ Build -> Settings -> GCC C++ Compiler -> Miscellaneous. It works now!

But how to add this flag by default for all C++ projects? Anybody?

Comment: Did you look into Window -> Preferences -> C/C++ -> Build -> Settings?

Comment: I do not have this option sadly.

Comment: How do I handle this situation with cmake?

Comment: @UserK in case your compiler is c++11 capable: `set (CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)`

Answer (score 61):

According to the [GCC page for C++11](http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html):

To enable C++0x support, add the command-line parameter -std=c++0x to your g++ command line. Or, to enable GNU extensions in addition to C++0x extensions, add -std=gnu++0x to your g++ command line. GCC 4.7 and later support -std=c++11 and -std=gnu++11 as well.

Did you compile with `-std=gnu++0x` ?

Comment: I tried adding -std=gnu++0x and -std=c++0x command line parameters but getting the same problem.

I added it under Project Properties -> C/C++ Build -> Discovery Options -> Compiler Invocation Arguments. Is that the right place?

Comment: Probably, but it sounds like the other answer is more grounded in reality. :)

Comment: Hi Rob, I noticed one thing now. The IDE does not pick up the compiler argument -std=c++0x although I have added it under Project Properties -> C/C++ Build -> Discovery Options -> Compiler Invocation Arguments. So I tried the command line build 'g++ "../CPP.cpp" -std=gnu++0x -std=c++0x' in a terminal and it compiles fine; produces the binary, which runs successfully. So the IDE does not consider the compiler option specified. The makefile generated does not bear the compiler argument -std=c++0x. Not sure how to force the IDE to consider the compiler argument supplied!

Comment: You only need one of the options, and I suggest the `-std=c++11`or -std=c++0x` depending on your compiler version. The `gnu++0x` enables non-standard extensions.

Comment: Finally found out what to do. Add the -std=c++0x compiler argument under Project Properties -> C/C++ Build -> Settings -> GCC C++ Compiler -> Miscellaneous. It works now!

But how to add this flag by default for all C++ projects? Anybody?

Thanks
Vivek Ragunathan

Answer (score 6):

You are using g++ 4.6 version you must invoke the flag -std=c++0x to compile

> **g++ -std=c++0x *.cpp -o output**

Answer (score 4):

Is that an actual compiler error or a Code Analysis error? Some times the code analysis can be a bit sketchy and report non-valid errors.

To turn off code analysis for the project, right click on your project in the Project Explorer, click on Properties, then go to the C/C++ General tab, then Code Analysis. Then click on "Use Project Settings" and disable the ones that you do not wish for.

Also, are you sure you are compiling with the C++11 compiler?

Comment: Upvoted to counter the downvote.  This is almost certainly the problem.

Comment: Thank you. I have run into this issue way to many times, so I thought it was worth mentioning.

Comment: I don't see a code analysis item under C/C++ General tab in my Eclipse project properties. I am using g++4.6. Hope that implements C++11 features, specifically nullptr and auto. Thanks.

Comment: Interesting, what version of eclipse do you have? To find out go to Help -> About Eclipse. I am on "Build id: 20120216-1857" and I do not have a problem with seeing it.

Comment: Snapshot of Help -> About Eclipse

Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.
Version: Helios Release
Build id: 20100617-1415

Thanks

Comment: I am not sure if even have code analysis at all with that build, so that may not be your error. Or it may just be in a different place. I did notice though that is not the version I have. I have the latest from http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-cc-developers-includes-incubating-components/indigosr2 . Perhaps if you update you may fix your error.

Comment: OK I noticed one thing now. The IDE does not pick up the compiler argument -std=c++0x although I have added it under Project Properties -> C/C++ Build -> Discovery Options -> Compiler Invocation Arguments. So I tried the command line build 'g++ "../CPP.cpp" -std=gnu++0x -std=c++0x' in a terminal and it compiles fine; produces the binary, which runs successfully. So the IDE does not consider the compiler option specified. The makefile generated does not bear the compiler argument -std=c++0x. Not sure how to force the IDE to consider the compiler argument supplied!

Comment: Finally found out what to do. Add the -std=c++0x compiler argument under Project Properties -> C/C++ Build -> Settings -> GCC C++ Compiler -> Miscellaneous. It works now!

But how to add this flag by default for all C++ projects? Anybody?

Thanks
Vivek Ragunathan

Comment: @Vivek Ragunathan: Did you look into Window -> Preferences -> C/C++ -> Build -> Settings?

Comment: So, can you please explain if it's possible to introduce `nullptr` and other keywords to code analyzer or not? I would like to stay with code analyzer...

Answer (score 3):

Go to Settings -> Compiler...
And add flag to "Have g++ follow the coming C++0x ISO C++ language standard [std=c++0x]

Answer (score 1):

Trying with a different version of gcc worked for me - gcc 4.9 in my case.

Answer (score 0):

I add the ",-std=c++0x" after "-c -fmessage-length=0"，under Project Properties -> C/C++ Build -> Settings -> GCC C++ Compiler -> Miscellaneous. Dont't forget to add the comma "," as the seperator.